# Operation Must Use An Updateable Query Error with Access 2007 and SQL 2005 Backend

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm using VB code in Access 2007 with a SQL 2005 backbone. My SQL server resides on a separate machine and the code below runs on a client. The problem is when I run the UPDATE command below I get an error "Operation Must Use An Updateable Query". I know this is common, but all my research on the internet didn't produce anything similar to my situation.

```
Dim MyDB as DAO.Database
Dim sSQL as String
sSQL = "UPDATE tblBMS_Batch SET Status = 70 WHERE Batch_ID = 108582"
MyDB.Execute sSQL
```

The table set up is below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBMS_Batch](
[Batch_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SDetail_Id] [int] NULL,
[Destination_Id] [int] NULL,
[Batch_Number] [smallint] NULL,
[Line_Number] [smallint] NULL,
[Packing_Number] [smallint] NULL,
[Start_Time] [datetime] NULL,
[End_Time] [datetime] NULL,
[Status] [smallint] NULL,
[Batch_Note] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[Employee_Number] [smallint] NULL,
[PLC_BatchNumber] [smallint] NULL,
[Packing_BatchLetter] [varchar](3) NULL,
[Number_Bags] [smallint] NULL,
[Abort_Status] [bit] NULL,
[Return_Bags] [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

The error occurs on the Execute. To make it more confusing the exact same UPDATE works in SQL directly, and I can also update that table in other VB code in a separate application on the same machine (albeit using ADODB connection).

Any ideas? I'm pretty stumped here. Thanks in advance.

Jason

Comment: Did you select a unique identifier when you linked the table or does the table have a unique key?

Comment: Doesn't the string have to be in double quotes? `sSQL = "UPDATE tblBMS_Batch SET Status = 70 WHERE Batch_ID = 108582"`

Comment: I doubt if it would get as far as failing at execute if the string was not quoted.

Comment: What driver are you using to access the data? Are you using ODBC Linked Tables?

Comment: Yes sorry the string does have quotes. I'm using the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database Engine Object Library I believe. And yes I'm using ODBC linked tables

Comment: Have you tried running the query in the MS Access query designer? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: I just updated my original question with the table information. Also I confirmed that the same SQL statement copied into a Access query yields the same error message

Comment: so according to your table design there is no primary key? Access cannot update unless there is a Primary key or unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to try this SQL:

```
UPDATE tblBMS_Batch SET Status = '70' WHERE Batch_ID = '108582'
```

Are the fields stored as number or text? If text then the above may work as Access is strict with it's syntax whereas MS SQL can compensate between text/number fields in SQL as long as the value matches (always a nice touch I thought)

Alternatively, if this SQL has to be run via Access then you could run it as a pass through query to the SQL server and it should then run in the same way as it would if you were executing it on the server.

Comment: If the query he is showing works in SQL Server Management Studio I doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: The two fields in question are Ints. I had tried with single quotes and just tried again to confirm that it doesn't work. Still same error.

Comment: @user1397315 No worries, a bit a long shot that one, have you tried the pass-through query approach?

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar with the pass-through query approach? Are you referring to just an Access query or something else? I'm willing to try anything! And thanks for your response by the way.

Comment: @JasonR Pass-through queries are a built in option in Access, essentially it lets you write your SQL in the same syntax you would in SQL Studio and when it runs it executes against the server and returns the results, so if as you say the original SQL works in studio, it should in theory work as a pass-through, on the properites though remember to change the "returns records" to no otherwise it will try and run it as a SELECT query. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968

Comment: @MattDonnan - Thanks, I'll follow that and try to set that up. The very strange thing is the DB I'm connecting to has dozens of other tables that I'm interfacing to (including UPDATES) without any issues. Can you think of anything in my Access set up or the SQL table set up that could cause this?

Comment: @JasonR Unfortunately I can't think of anything off the top of my head, a mystery.

Comment: @MattDonnan - The pass through query does work as expected, so thank you for that. I'd prefer to figure out why this isn't working so I'm going to the leave the question unanswered for a bit longer to see if I get any other responses but if not I'll mark your response. Thanks again

Comment: I think using a pass through query is little more than a crude work-around for this problem. If it were me I'd rather get to the bottom of it as well.

Comment: I agree finding the problem is important, although HK how can you say "crude" after all this is the purpose of Microsoft including the pass-thru functionality. I always favour running queries server side if the option is available rather than locally in Access, otherwise why not just use Jet/Ace tables because if you don't take advantage of the server then it will not bring you any increased performance.

Comment: My biggest complaint with pass through queries is that you have to rewrite the saved queries' SQL "definition" every time before executing it (if you have parameters that change anyway). I guess this seems little crude to me. It seems that when you start moving away from native Access behavior you have to work a lot harder to make things work. At that point I wonder if you shouldn't be using .Net instead.

Comment: @HK1 - I've always been a little baffled about using Access with SQL backbone anyhow... I agree that .NET is the way to go. My customer dictated this to me. No way I'd chose this architecture willingly :) As for the SQL definition I sure wish they'd let us pass variables like with regular queries...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you need to use the dbSeeChanges option when updating a SQL Server table that contains an Identity field. Also, it may have been oversight on your part but I don't see where you are setting MyDB to anything.

```
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
Set MyDB = CurrentDb
Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = "UPDATE tblBMS_Batch SET [Status] = 70 WHERE Batch_ID = 108582"
MyDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
Set MyDB = Nothing
```

I've looked several places online and it appears, to my surprise, that the word Status actually is not a reserved word in SQL Server or in MS Access but I put the brackets around it anyway, just in case.

Comment: Yes I forgot to include the Set MyDB = CurrentDB but that is in my code. I tried the Execute as you have it and still get the same error... its very strange but it seems to be something with the Table definition or the way Access is interfacing to this table (although I have dozens of other tables I interface with in Access the exact same way)

Comment: I created the same table you have listed above and I was able to run your update statement, but only with dbSeeChanges. I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express and Access 2007 SP2. You might check to make sure that you have all the latest updates installed. Have you also tried restarting SQL Server and restarting the client computer?

Comment: Thanks for attempting to recreate my issue. Unfortunantly I'm in a production environment so I can't change any of the service packs and I can't restart the server. I can try restarting the client.